# EaselJs canvas dragstart event not bubbling to parent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I have a number of canvas elements, which need to be draggable. (not elements within the canvas element, i mean the actual canvas DOM node)

The code looks like this

```
<div class="top-parent" draggable="true">
  <div class="inner-parent">
     <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I just have a regular canvas element which hasn't been initialized with createjs the drag drop library i'm working works fine (I believe it works off the html5 dragstart event). If I use `new createjs.Stage(canvas);` the drag and drop functionality doesn't work, it appears that the dragstart event is not bubbling up, or perhaps not even being registered.

I tried `stage.enableDOMEvents = true;` this doesn't appear to work - which i guess makes sense because it should be the default option but I thought I would try anyway.

Comment: Are you saying the dragstart is not bubbling outside of the canvas? EaselJS uses the CreateJS event model, which is similar to DOM level 3 events, but not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EaselJS Stage instances call `preventDefault()` on native touch/mouse events by default, to prevent the canvas from being selected (and getting an ugly selection highlight). Try disabling this functionality by using: `myStage.preventSelection = false;`. That should let those events progress normally, which may allow your drag and drop library to function.

If you are not using mouse events in the `Stage` at all (ex. DisplayObject instances with click, mouseDown, etc handlers), you can completely unsubscribe the Stage from the DOM events by using: `myStage.enableDOMEvents(false);`. Note that `enableDOMEvents` is a method, whereas you are trying to use it as a property in your example.

Comment: Setting `stage.preventSelection = false` was the fix, cheers :)

Comment: thanks for the solution, just to let you now I have another related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382935/easeljs-canvas-draggable-true-does-not-show-ghost-image, would love your input

Comment: And as a side-note: if you don't want the highlighting you can set `user-select: none;` on the canvas (http://caniuse.com/#search=user-select)