# Easeljs (MovieClip) canvas draggable=true does not show ghost image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I have a canvas element which has animations within it that are facilitated by EaselJS. The canvas element has a parent div wrapping it with draggable set to true.

```
<div class="outer-parent" draggable="true">
  <div class="inner-parent">
   <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

The draggable event is working (I originally had issues with this, but the problem was resolved here: [EaselJs canvas dragstart event not bubbling to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366131/easeljs-canvas-dragstart-event-not-bubbling-to-parent)), however the canvas element does not appear to show a "ghost". If I add a border to `outer-parent` I can see the draggable moving, but within the border there is nothing - it's 100% transparent.

I checked to see whether this was an issue specific to canvas and not easeljs - it appears to be an easeljs issue as the ghost works fine in this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNVNpr.

Here is an example of it not working with easeljs and movieclipjs
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGzwYY
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNEOwB (running this script exported from flash)

What could be causing the ghost not to show, and how can I get it to show?

Comment: I just tested, and it seems to work as expected. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdKeNJ

Comment: this is an example closer to what i'm doing this uses createjs movie clip and has some animation

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGzwYY, the ghost does show but only the background, the animated element does not show. Here's the script it is running (exported direct from flash) : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNEOwB?

Comment: Created a pen to confirm that this isn't a canvas animation limitation
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doKXVK

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though this is a browser behaviour in Chrome. All of your examples work as expected in Safari, however, in Chrome there seems to be a maximum canvas size before it "drops" the canvas content in the ghost. For example, for me a `200x300` canvas works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJKNEq

I'm not sure how you'd work around this, since it seems to be a limitation of the browser. Scaling it up works, but is probably not ideal.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNEVaZ

Comment: Looks like you're right there, good find - seems to be at exactly 220 that the bug appears, odd...